# Download a file directly to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

Given a resource link, for example:

```
http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png
```

Is there a way to download that png directly to S3 (preferably using Boto)? If so, how would this be done?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Any 'download to S3' implicitly means 'download and then upload to S3' - whether you do that upload manually or a script or library like boto does it.

If using a script or library (boto) it would download the image to a file-system attached to the system it was running on - your local workstation or a server - and then use the AWS keys and libraries to upload it to S3.

Answer (score 12):

You can use urllib2 to fetch the file and use the response object to write it into S3 using boto.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import urllib2

request = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png')
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

conn = S3Connection("MYAWSID", "MYAWSSECRET")
bucket = conn.create_bucket('MyBucket')
k = Key(bucket)
k.name = "logo3w"
k.set_contents_from_string(response.read(), {'Content-Type': response.info().gettype()})
```

If you don't have the packages you can install them from PIP using

```
pip install urllib2_file
pip install boto
```